# Android recycler view resizes when parent fragment redisplayed after showing DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontally scrolling recycler view withiin a nested scrollview. The view is in a fragment. A cardview is wrapped around the recycler.
Everything works perfectly well until I show a DialogFragment. On it's dismissal the recyclerview elements seem to lose their sizing / padding.
After you start swiping, it recovers it's correct siziing.

Answer (score 0):

This in the dialog theme was causing the problem. Remove it and problem goes away.

```
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```